# Lower bounds for Poisson Binomial distribution tail probability

Tags: probability-inequalities, poisson-binomial-distribution

Consider a Poisson Binomial distribution $X = X_1+X_2+\dotsm+X_n$, where $X_i$ is $Bernoulli(p_i$). What I am looking is a lower bound on $P(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i \leq k)$, where $k<\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i$.

I looked at other relevant questions, but they do not provide such bounds, such as [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14471/reverse-chernoff-bound), where the accepted answer provides a bound assuming all $p_i < \frac{1}{2}$, whereas I have no such assumption (they may be small on average). Any relevant literature that I may have missed in my search will be helpful as well.